# Using generics with com.sun.codemodel

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

Using [com.sun.codemodel](https://codemodel.dev.java.net/), I would like to generate a generic LinkedList field. I can create a raw field using this code:

```
JDefinedClass masterClass;
String detailName;
JDefinedClass detailClass;
JFieldVar detailField = masterClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, LinkedList.class, detailName);
```

But I could not find a way to create a LinkedList with a generic type of `detailClass`.

Comment: you have a typo: `masterClass` in one case and `masterClazz` in the other. (tangent: why the @#$@#$ does everyone have to use "clazz" with its intentional misspelling, instead of something a little less jarring on the eyes like "cl" or "class1", or even just "class" when it's part of an identifier like "masterClass" or "detailClass" in your case)

Comment: @JasonS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529974/why-do-java-programmers-like-to-name-a-variable-clazz

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
JClass detailClass = codeModel.ref(String.class);
String detailName = "myLinkedListField";
JClass rawLLclazz = codeModel.ref(LinkedList.class);
JClass fieldClazz = rawLLclazz.narrow(detailClass);
JFieldVar detailField = def.field(JMod.PRIVATE, fieldClazz, detailName);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I somehow glanced over the doc for `narrow` since it looked like a typecast like in `javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow`.