# Difference between class and type

Tags: java, class, types

Being new to Java, I'm confused between the concepts of **class** and **type**.
For example, should the object `"Hello World!"` belong to the *type* `String` or *class* `String`? Or maybe both?

Comment: Not silly at all. I think a type is the general case. A class is a specific case of type as is interface which I've heard called a "pure" type.

Comment: +1 for what seems like a genuine question.

Comment: I see a voting war going on between the negatives and the positives :-D

Comment: Lately there seems to be an inclination to downvote any "beginner" style questions whether they're good or not. Its annoying, to say the least.

Comment: Also to downvote any question that the voter doesn't understand ...

Comment: I agree it's kind of rude to downvote as you say beginner questions, but whether is good or bad, all beginner questions have their answers just by searching the web. The problem and the reason people are downvoting is because this is leading to stack overflow :)

Comment: This is a great question - and the 3 votes to close are why we need to be able to vote to *keep open*.  I still remember back when I was learning Java that the OO jargon was the biggest impediment.

Comment: It's a not-bad question and surely doesn't warrant down-votes or close-votes, but I'm not sure I'd classify it as a "great" question.

Comment: It seems like the Java "camp" is more intolerant than for example C# where I don't see as many downvoted questions. I wonder why?

Comment: @nickecarlo There used to be a point in the FAQ, which seems to be taken out during the last year or so -- "the question shows serious lack of research and doesn't show signs of effort done to resolve it before asking the question". I find it annoying that there's A TON of bullshit questions that Google could solve instead of people here actually wasting their time explaining "programming 101" to others.

Comment: @TC1 is completely correct - if I didn't think it'd get removed for being rude, I'd comment on quite a lot of questions here with a "lmgtfy" link. These are distinctly _bad_ questions because they show no research effort - as such, they should be downvoted, unless we're accessing different versions of the downvote hover text

Comment: If you don't downvote you are eventually going to have a lot of questions like this, and all of us are going to miss that interesting one to help a fellow at need. Even with all comments and a proper answer, why didn't he accepted the correct offered answer? At least that, like a sign of good will

Comment: This is a legitimate question and shouldn't be closed unless a duplicate can be found. It was valid and clear from the beginning, but I tried to improve it with my edit.

Comment: @MattTaylor I am not very active on Stack Overflow, but still want to share my perspective.  For me,as far as programming questions is concerned, Stack Overflow is almost the entire web, because  it pops up all the times. How is this possible?  Because, Stack Overflow seems to care to provide the answers to all valid questions, even simple ones. It does not say, "go see elsewhere for the answer.". Your comment goes in the opposite direction. Your comment says, if it is elsewhere, this is where you must look.  I prefer the view point of Paul Bellora.

Comment: six years later, and this is the first hit on my google search and it provides a quick answer that is to the point. Thank you.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

A class is a type.  An interface is a type.  A primitive is a type. An array is a type.

Therefore, every type is also either a class (including an enum constant), an interface, a primitive, or an array.

There are two distinct categories of types: primitive types and reference types:

- A variable of primitive type always holds a primitive value of that same type. Such a value can only be changed by assignment operations on that variable.
- A variable of reference type always holds the value of a reference to an object. All objects, including arrays, support the methods of class `Object`. The reference types are class types (including enum types), interface types, and array types.

Every piece of data has a type which defines its structure, namely how much memory it takes up, how it is laid out, and more importantly, how you can interact with it.

Examples of primitive types:

1. `int`
2. `float`
3. `char`
4. `boolean`

Examples of class types:

1. [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
2. [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)
3. [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html)
4. [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
5. [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Examples of interface types:

1. [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)
2. [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
3. [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
4. [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Examples of array types:

1. `int[]`
2. `String[]`
3. `Integer[][][]`

Basically, anything that you can refer to as a variable has a type, and classes are a kind of a type.

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html

Comment: I won't make the edit myself because I'm not certain that's what you meant to write, but it *might* work better saying that classes are "a kind of a type" rather than "a type of a type".

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, that is a better way of saying it.  I'll update it.

Comment: @PaulBellora Good call, I added arrays

Comment: I went ahead and made some edits - lemme know anything is confusing and feel free to tweak them.

Comment: You forgot the null type (see JLS 4.1).

Comment: Typical developer of me to forget about null references :)

Comment: How about abstract class itself?

Comment: @AndyDong An abstract class is still a class.

Comment: What about annotation types?

Comment: List<Object> and List<String> are two types from one interface. Your explanation is incorrect.

Comment: Good answer. I would add a note that the entire point of writing your own class is to define your own custom type.

Answer (score 11):

**TLDR** -  Class is one of the Type in Java.

Note - To fully understand the answer, you must have a little idea about generics in Java.

---

To understand the difference let us first understand what a **Type** is in Java.

According to [JLS SE 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) ,

> There are two kinds of **types** in the Java programming language:
>   **primitive types** ([§4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)) and **reference types** (§4.3).

What is primitive Type ?

> a) The integral types are **byte, short, int, and long**, whose values are
>   8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers,
>   respectively, and **char,** whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers
>   representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).
>
> b) The floating-point types are **float**, whose values include the 32-bit
>   IEEE 754 floating-point numbers, and **double**, whose values include the
>   64-bit IEEE 754 floating-point numbers.
>
> c) The **boolean** type has exactly two values: true and false.

Now , let us come to what is reference type ?

> There are four kinds of reference types: **class types** ([§8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)), **interface
>   types** ([§9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1)), **type variables** ([§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)), and **array types** ([§10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)).

Let us discuss one by one.

If you see how in JLS , **Class** is defined like this :

> A **class declaration** specifies a new named reference type.
>
> There are two kinds of class declarations: **normal class declarations
>   and enum declarations**.

```
ClassDeclaration:
NormalClassDeclaration 
EnumDeclaration
NormalClassDeclaration:
{ClassModifier} class TypeIdentifier [TypeParameters] [Superclass] [Superinterfaces] ClassBody
```

You see that `[TypeParameters]`, this shows that class type includes those 
 generic classes too.

```
class Example<T>{

}
```

The class type will be called `Example`

**In short , a class type covers our enums , our regular (non generic) classes like `String` etc and our generic classes too.**

Similarly , I hope interface and array types is also clear. By array Type we mean like `int[]`, `String[]` etc.

Let us come to the last part -  Type variables. What are they ?

> A type variable is an unqualified identifier used as a type in class,
>   interface, method, and constructor bodies.

Let us understand by the example in the JLS below it.

```
class Test {
    <T extends C & I> void test(T t) {  
        t.mI();           // OK
        t.mCPublic();     // OK 
        t.mCProtected();  // OK 
        t.mCPackage();    // OK

    } 
}
```

You see that your object in the method parameter is of type `T`. Yes , this `T` is Type variable and is/can be used as a reference . Yes it is. (Could not understand this strange example - Learn what is generic method in Java)

This completes the answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Type" is the more inclusive category. Variables in Java can have three kinds of types: the 8 "primitive" types like int and float, interfaces, and classes. Values (as opposed to variables) can be primitive or class instances.

Answer (score 4):

This is a question about programming terminology, and as expected, there is yet another answer that could be considered valid.

The Java type system, as exposed by the reflection API, has two types: [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class and [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) interface, which the former implements. In this system, a class (an element that is described by an instance of `Class<T>`) is any type created with the keyword `class` or `interface`, any primitive type, any array thereof, and `void`. Everything else is just a `Type`.

So what is everything else? While a class in this context is everything the runtime sees and has access to when considering the capabilities of an object, a type, in general, is everything the compiler sees. This can be a [parametrized type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) (like `ArrayList<String>` – remember that type erasure causes every `ArrayList<T>` to map to the same class at runtime), a [generic type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) created as a part of a method or class declaration, a [wildcard type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/WildcardType.html), and any [array thereof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericArrayType.html). Those types are exposed by API methods in all places where type erasure is not in effect,
like when traversing parameter types or base types.

Answer (score 4):

Types are associated with compile-time entities such as variables and expressions, whilst classes are associated with run-time entities such as in-memory objects. Consider the language used in the specification [15.5. Expressions and Run-Time Checks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.5)

> If the type of an expression is a reference type, then the class of
> the referenced object... An expression whose type is a reference type may be tested using `instanceof` to find out whether the class of the object referenced by the run-time value of the expression...

Robert Harper, author of [Practical Foundations for Programming Languages](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf), makes the following [distinction](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/dynamic-languages-are-static-languages/#comment-2935)

> I do think it is important to distinguish carefully classes, which may
> be attached to objects, from types, which are static classifiers

Java generics are one example where this distinction is relevant. First consider the following snippet

```
String greeting = "Hello" + " " + "world!";
```

- the compile-time type of the variable `greeting` is `String`
- the compile-time type of the expression `"Hello" + " " + "world!"` is `String`
- the run-time class of the instantiated object `Hello world!` referred to by variable `greetings`  is `String`

It appears in the above case the distinction does not matter much, however let's try similar reasoning on the following snippet

```
List<String> greetings = List.of("Hello World!");
```

- the compile-time type of the variable `greetings` is `List<String>`
- the compile-time type of the expression `new ArrayList("Hello World!")` is `List<String>`
- the run-time class of the instantiated object referred to by variable `greetings` is `ImmutableCollections$List1`

Now we see there is indeed a difference between type `List<String>` and class `ImmutableCollections$List1`. We see the compile-time type is "richer" in information where compiler is aware the element type is `String` whilst at run-time the element type information is lost due to type erasure.

Here is another demonstration of the difference between types and classes

```
jshell> /set feedback verbose
|  Feedback mode: verbose

jshell> List.of("Hi", "Hello")
$1 ==> [Hi, Hello]
|  created scratch variable $1 : List<String>

jshell> List.of(42, -11)
$2 ==> [42, -11]
|  created scratch variable $2 : List<Integer>

jshell> $1.getClass() == $2.getClass()
$3 ==> true
|  created scratch variable $3 : boolean
```

Note how types of expressions `List.of("Hi", "Hello")` and `List.of(42, -11)` are different, and yet the classes of corresponding instantiated objects are the same.

Answer (score 2):

"Type" defines 'what type of data it is'

Ex: "hello world" is a String -->   "hello world" is String type (String is not a premetive data unlike int .. so we can say "hello world" is a string class type)

10 is a int   --> 10 is a integer data type.

Comment: Be careful with using integer to explain an int since Integer != int in Java.