# What is meaning of property/field to have the same type as its class

Tags: c#

I have the next code in c #:

```
class Person
{
     private Person variable; // what this line mean
     ....
}
```

What does it mean for type of `variable` to be 'Person' ? It is not yet completely defined... Why would one use such class?

Comment: Take a look into : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16600781/5242840

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty common for class to have variables of its own type. Standard case - element of binary tree:

```
 class TreeNode
 {
       public int Data {get;set;}
       public TreeNode Left {get;set;}          
       public TreeNode Right {get;set;}
 }
```

This means that instance of the class *refers* to some other instances it relates to in some way. Commonly it is some sort of parent-child (like in sample above) or ownership relation (i.e. `CarComponent` has more `CarComponent` like engine has valves).

As for naming of such construct - there is no common name for that. Sometimes "recursive class" or "self-referencing class" are used, but there is no formal name to my knowledge.

Note:  `class` is reference type adding reference to an instance of the same type as field is perfectly fine. Note that this will not work with `struct` (as data must be part of the same object).