# Inheritance in wildcard generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

Since we can do

```
ArrayList<?> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Can we say `ArrayList<?>` is superclass of `ArrayList<Integer>` ?
Is the above example hence depicts polymorphism ?

**Update**: In general , If `A<T>` is superclass of `B<T>` , then

```
A<?> obj = new B<Integer>();
```

Then is right to say `A<?>` is super class of `B<Integer>` ?

Comment: I thought the unbounded wildcard is already covered somewhere in SO, but apparently it's not the case.

Comment: No, [`AbstractList<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html), [`AbstractCollection<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html), and `Object` are all superclasses of [`ArrayList<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Generics are not covariant, that means that a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`. See [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p/2745301#2745301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR** :

> Can we say `ArrayList<?>` is superclass of `ArrayList<Integer>` ?

**NO** but we can say it is supertype of `ArrayList<Integer>`

> Then is right to say `A<?>` is super class of `B<Integer>` ?

**YES** and we can also say it is supertype of `B<Integer>`

Also note that inheritance is used only in context of subclass or super class and not subtype or supertype.

[Quick Reference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ204)

---

First thing you need to understand is [class is a type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343647/2844702) in java.
We will see below that wherever it is **valid** to use the term sub/super class , it is valid to use sub/super type but not vice versa

Let me now define superclass. According to [JLS 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)

> Given a (possibly generic) class declaration for `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n ≥ 0,
>   C ≠ Object) (Fi here is type parameter), the direct superclass of the class type `C<F1,...,Fn>` is
>   the type **given in the extends clause** of the declaration of C if an
>   extends clause is present, or Object otherwise.
>
> Let `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0) be a generic class declaration. The direct
>   superclass of the parameterized class type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where Ti (1 ≤
>   i ≤ n) is a type (argument), is `D<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>`, where `D<U1,...,Uk>` is the
>   direct superclass of `C<F1,...,Fn>`, and θ is the substitution
>   [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].
>
> A class A is a subclass of class C if either of the following is true:
>
> a) A is the direct subclass of C 
> b)There exists a class B such that A
>   is a subclass of B, and B is a subclass of C, applying this definition
>   recursively.
>
> Class C is said to be a superclass of class A whenever A is a subclass
>   of C.

To explain the thing in little simple words , consider a simpler example :
`C<F1,...,Fn>`  be `ArrayList<T>` and `C<T1,...,Tn>` will be say `ArrayList<Integer>` in above definition. `T` is type parameter and we instantiate it with `Integer` which is type argument.

[[ What did we meant by θ is the substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn] ? ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453014/2844702)

Now, Does `A<?>` comes in extends clause of `A<Integer>` ? (I know it is stupid to ask such a structure , but let us be strict with definition) . No it does not. Generally , in extends we mention a different class type altogether.

Now, let us see definition of sub/super type. By [JLS 4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2)

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0), the direct
>   supertypes of the parameterized type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤
>   n) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> 1. `D<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>`, where `D<U1,...,Uk>` is a generic type which is a
>      direct supertype of the generic type `C<T1,...,Tn>` and θ is the
>      substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].
> 2. `C<S1,...,Sn>`, where Si contains Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) (§4.5.1).
> 3. The type Object, if `C<F1,...,Fn>` is a generic interface type with no
>      direct superinterfaces.
> 4. The raw type `C`.

Now by this definition , according to point 2

> `C<S1,...,Sn>`, where Si contains Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) (§4.5.1).

`?` contains `Integer`([Reference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ209)). Hence, this makes `A<?>` supertype of `A<Integer>`.

You can easily see the point 1 of this definition, includes the subclass definition in itself.

The second part of question , where We have said `A<T>` extends `B<T>` , makes it fall under both definitions.

Lastly, we see what inheritance mean. By [JLS 8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)

> A class C **inherits** from its **direct superclass** all concrete
>   methods m (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all
>   of the following are true: [...]

Comment: Hi Ben could you answer my question about this line `D<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>, where D<U1,...,Uk> is the direct superclass of C<F1,...,Fn>, and θ is the substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].`? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434267/confusion-over-generics-subtyping-in-java-specs

Answer (score 0):

Here inheritance applies to generic classes not generic arguments

that is to say `ArrayList<?>`  is not super class of `ArrayList<Integer>`

It is same class with different type parameters . If you would have used any  other type parameter than `<?>` there the code would have not worked. even with superclass of Integer