# Confusion over generics subtyping in java specs?

Tags: java, subtyping

I'm reading java specs 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2
and this line confuses me:

> `D<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>`, where `D<U1,...,Uk>` is a generic type which is a
>   direct supertype of the generic type C and θ is the
>   substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].

is `Uk θ` here casting? and after substitution `D` becomes `D<(U1)T1,...,(Uk)Tk>`? If so why does the author omit the brackets in `Uk θ` as part of casting syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, the JLS mercifully decided to do away with this inscrutable construction; see, for example, the same section in JLS 17: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0), the direct
>   supertypes of the parameterized type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤
>   n) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> `D<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>`, where `D<U1,...,Uk>` is a generic type which is a
>   direct supertype of the generic type `C<F1,...,Fn>` and θ is the
>   substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].

Let us see an example.

```
public class D<U1,U2> {
}

//Note the order of F3,F4.
class C<F1,F2,F3,F4> extends D<F4,F3>{

}

class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        C<Integer,String,Float,Number> obj = new C<>();

        D<Float ,Number> obj2 = obj; // Compilation error

        D<Number ,Float> obj3 = obj; //This is fine


    }
}
```

What do you think `θ` is here ?

`θ` = [F1:= Integer , F2:= String, F3:= Float, F4:= Number ]

Now `D<Number,Float>` is the correct supertype. But not `D<Float,Number>`. Why ?

Because of `Ui θ`. So what does this mean ?

Well , it just means substitute i.e. Scan `U1 , U2 , ... till Uk` and if you find any `Fi` , then replace it by `Ti`.

In our example , it means Scan `F4` and `F3` of class D. Did you have `F4` and `F3` in θ ? Yes.
Then `F4`,`F3` of `D` **have to be** as defined in `θ`.

**Note** : The answer is as per my understanding. I don't have any concrete reference of what `Uk θ` means in Java type semantics.

Comment: Thank you very much! That really makes a lot of sense! Just one tiny point I think is that there should be a constrain `k <= n`, although the java doc doesn't mention that whatsoever. Thanks again!

Comment: Good point. Even I was thinking that. But then if you notice , they are applying `θ` on each U1, U2 ,... ,Uk. This clearly means that {U1, U2 ,... ,Uk} is subset of {F1,F2,..,Fn} as each Ui have to one of the F's as they are all type parameter and not type argument. This means k<=n. Again, this is my guess. Not very sure.

Comment: You're absolutely right, `k <= n` ought to be a prerequisite of using `Uk θ` so no need to explicitly denote that.

Answer (score 1):

Not casting. It's the mathy language used to describe a type.

In code, it's saying that if:

```
interface D<A, B> {}
interface C<A, B> extends D<A, B> {}

class Y implements D<String, Number> {}
class X implements C<String, Integer> {} // Note Integer is a subtype of Number
```

Then this compiles:

```
D d = new X();
```

Comment: Thanks Bohemian your code is very insightful but I'm still bit confused. I learned from another post that `:=` means assignment. However I can't find anything about the usage of `Uk θ`, it may be some sort of math transform notation but I still wonder is there any formal definition of that?

Comment: @mzoz I greatly appreciate your question and your focus. I had the same question, and I too cannot find an answer. Perhaps my phrasing may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502823/in-the-java-language-specification-version-11-section-4-10-2-how-do-i-read-u%e2%82%96