# In the Java Language Specification version 11, section 4.10.2, how do I read Uₖ θ?

Tags: java, java-11, jls

(I'm aware of a [previous question in this area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434267/confusion-over-generics-subtyping-in-java-specs) but you'll notice that the root of the original poster's issue was never resolved. My question, like theirs, is notational in nature.)

In the Java Language Specification, version 11 (but interestingly [no longer in JLS 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2), probably because it's hard to understand), it says, in part, [in section 4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2):

> Given a generic type declaration C<F₁,…,Fₙ> (*n* > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type C<T₁,…,Tₙ>, where Tᵢ (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> D<U₁ θ,…,Uₖ θ>, where D<U₁,…,Uₖ> is a generic type which is a direct supertype of the generic type C<F₁,…,Fₙ> and θ is the substitution [F₁:=T₁,…,Fₙ:=Tₙ].

Here are (possibly incorrect!) assumptions I am making:

- θ means, loosely, "substitute formal type parameters with actual type arguments" because of the [meta-notation in section 1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.3).
- C<F₁,…,Fₙ> represents, say, `public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>` (*n* = 1), and C<T₁,…,Tₙ> represents, say, `public class MyStringCollection implements Collection<String>` (so Tₙ = T₁). Here, F₁ is the `E` in `Collection<E>`, and T₁ is `String`.

  - (I'm guessing that the author(s) chose C as a symbol because they're talking about a **C**lass declaration.)
- D is a direct supertype of the raw type C, so, say, `Iterable`.  (I'm also guessing that the author(s) chose D as a symbol because they're talking about a type that is derived from C, so the "next symbol after C" is D.)
- *k* is unbounded, but I'm assuming it is supposed to be 1 ≤ *k* ≤ *n*, and the fact that its bounds are left unmentioned makes me think my hypothesis is correct
- Uₖ is the replacement-by-θ of Tₙ (my possibly incorrect hypothesis only! **This is my question!**), *i.e.* the result of applying θ to Fₖ, so since *n* is 1 (`Collection` takes exactly *n* = 1 type parameter `E`), then *k* is also 1, so we apply θ to F₁, which according to the definition of θ yields T₁, which is `String`, so therefore D<U₁> is `Iterable<String>`.

  - (Quick sanity check: can a reference of type `Iterable<String>` be assigned a reference of type `Collection<String>`? Yes it can.)
  - (I'm also guessing that the author(s) chose U as a symbol because they're talking about a type that is derived from T, so the "next symbol after T" is U.)

My main question: **Is my hypothesis of how to read the notation construction "Uₖ θ" correct?  Does "Uₖ θ" mean "find Fₖ and apply θ to it"?**  If so, in what section can I find the justification—referring to the specification only—for this hypothesis?

My sub-question: if my hypothesis is correct, where can I find the meta-notation that defines notations such as "Uₖ θ", where " " appears to mean "apply the substitution function that follows to the *k*<sup>th</sup> occurrence of the thing that came before, on the *k*<sup>th</sup> occurrence of an element of the domain of the substitution function"?

(Such a meta-notation is not delineated in the specification itself (others, such as θ are, quite explicitly, which is greatly appreciated), and a quick search of conventional meta-notations didn't yield such a convention.)

Comment: Yes and no, but I am glad to see that question! You'll note that the poster of that question ends with the very same narrowly focused question I have here, without an answer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine by answering this question? Is there a specific piece of code you are trying to write, or do you think you have found a compiler bug? I ask because it sounds like what you are trying to figure out is off topic here, and would be a better fit on e.g. https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: To put it another way: It's purely a notational question. θ is defined unambiguously. U is a type. Uₖ is a type parameter. "Uₖ θ" is…? When you answer, what is your justification for your answer?

Comment: While it doesn't really fully answer my question, I can see that the notation comes from a variant of the lambda calculus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_substitution and squint a little bit.