# What is the difference between the class `Class` and the class `Type` in java?

Tags: java, class, reflection, types

I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600750/difference-between-class-and-type) that talks about the difference between classes and types in java

However, this talks about classes declared with the `class` keyword rather than the actual class `Class` in java. In Java, I can have a `Class<T>` where T is a class/interface/array type (and for primitives, `T` would be the autoboxed class, but the instance of `Class<T>` would be associated with the primitive type, such as int.class). Point is, `Class` is used with more than just class types.

**What is the difference between the class[`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and interface [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html)?** When would I ever use `Type` in a java program?

Comment: Did you bother to **read the documentation**? `Class`: represent *classes* and *interfaces* in a running Java application. `Type`: include *raw types*, *parameterized types*, *array types*, *type variables* and *primitive types*. `Type` is an interface. `Class` is a class *implementing* that interface. It's all right there in the javadoc to `Type`. You even linked the javadoc. Now **read it**.

Comment: @Andreas I did read that, but the documentation only provides technical details, whereas the answer below provides practical details as well.

Comment: @Andreas In addition, I already explained why "raw types, parameterized types, array types, type variables and primitive types" was unclear: `Class<int[]>` is possible, but at the same time `Class` "represent[s] classes and interfaces", so why would an `int[]` be possible as a type argument?

Comment: What other *practical* details is needed other than objects of type `GenericArrayType`, `ParameterizedType`, `TypeVariable`, and `WildcardType` are not `Class` objects, but are all `Type` objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Type` is a superinterface of `Class`. You won't generally need to use it unless you're doing reflection with generic types.

As an example, we can get the type of a field using [`Field.getType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()):

```
Class<?> c =
    String.class.getField("CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER")
        .getType();
```

The problem is that [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) is actually a `Comparator<String>`, and the above code will only get us `Comparator.class`. This doesn't work for us if we needed to know what the type argument was.

`Type` [and its uses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/class-use/Type.html) were added in Java 1.5 (along with generics) for this type of situation. We could instead use the method [`Field.getGenericType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType()):

```
Type t =
    String.class.getField("CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER")
        .getGenericType();
```

In this case, it would return an instance of [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html), with `Comparator.class` as its raw type and `String.class` in its type arguments:

```
ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
pt.getRawType(); // interface java.util.Comparator
pt.getActualTypeArguments(); // [class java.lang.String]
```

This part of the API isn't very well developed, but there are some better ones built around it, like [Guava `TypeToken`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html).

Comment: I thought the generic type isn't available at runtime due to type erasure. Am I missing something? How would `ParametrizedType#getActualTypeArguments` be able to determine it?

Comment: Some generic type information is stored in the class file. Otherwise the compiler wouldn't be able to work with compiled class files when you do something like import a library. Type erasure affects situations involving object instances: if you have, say an `ArrayList<String>` and an `ArrayList<Double>`, there's no way to tell them apart at run-time except to inspect their contents.