# Does R's S4 OOP system have a distinction between classes and types?

Tags: r, class, oop, types, r-s4

Big encapsulation-style languages, such as [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16600750/10319707), [Kotlin](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/programmer-dictionary-class-vs-type-vs-object-e6d1f74d1e2e?gi=447d6cc26ec1), or C#, have a distinction between classes and types. S4, being a generic-function style OOP system, is fundamentally different. But does it still have a class/type distinction of any kind?

Note this question is very similar to [Does R's S3 OOP system have a distinction between classes and types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73228092/does-rs-s3-oop-system-have-a-distinction-between-classes-and-types). It may have a similar, perhaps identical, answer. If there is a difference, explaining it would be helpful.

Comment: What do you think the distinction between classes and types is in Java, Kotlin and C#? Are you simply referring to the distinction between primitive and user-defined types? Because that has nothing to do with “encapsulation-style languages”, whatever that may actually be.

Comment: @KonradRudolph For example, I often hear it said that "a type is a contract; a class is its implementation".

Comment: That isn’t really related to encapsulation, and it’s a pretty vague and generic statement that can effectively applied anywhere.