# Returning a string array of an objects methods

Tags: java, reflection

Is there an easy way of return an objects public method names as a string array?

My limited Java knowledge can only come up with using a reader and scan through the .java file .

Comment: Look into reflection.

Comment: Why don't you google it before posting a question.

Comment: Down-vote from me. This is trivially Google-able.

Comment: @DerekParker I searched for the phrase "[java list public methods](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+list+public+methods)". Perhaps I'm a Google wizard in comparison to you, but I suspect not.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Class#getMethods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--):

> Returns an array containing `Method` objects reflecting **all the public methods of the class or interface represented by this `Class` object**, including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces.

```
public static List<String> getPublicMethods(Class<?> clazz) {
    Method[] publicMethods = clazz.getMethods();
    List<String> methodNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Method method : publicMethods) {
        methodNames.add(method.getName());
    }
    return methodNames;
}
```

If you want it strictly as an array, use the above method altogether with `List#toArray`:

```
public static String[] getPublicMethods(Class<?> clazz) {
    Method[] publicMethods = clazz.getMethods();
    List<String> methodNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Method method : publicMethods) {
        methodNames.add(method.getName());
    }
    return methodNames.toArray(new String[publicMethods.length]);
}
```

Comment: `clazz`? :-)...English answer should end with an English code...

Comment: @YairNevet it's not the first time I've seen `clazz`. You can check [`ClassUtils` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/2.5.6/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java) from Spring :).

Comment: Now it is more clear: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2530174/952310](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2530174/952310)

Comment: @YairNevet see? There's no problem to avoid the rule in very specific cases like this. Apart of that, the rest of the code is wrote in proper English (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), for example:

```
Class aClass = MyObject.class;
Method[] methods = aClass.getMethods();
```

Now, you can project a string array from this array (`Method[]`):

```
 List<String> methodNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        methodNames.add(method.getName());
    }
```

And play with it as you wish, for example:

```
for (String methodName : methodNames) {
     System.out.println(methodName);
}
```